# Angular $http Update not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, controller, edit

Trying to update an object with the code below. When I save the update, it will show the update on the immediate page, but when I reload, the entire object and all key values are empty.

Angular Controller:

```
ListingShowController.$inject = ['$http', '$stateParams', '$location'];
function ListingShowController ($http, $stateParams, $location) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.editListing = function (listing) {
    $http({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: '/api/listings/'+$stateParams.listingId,
      data: listing
    }).then(function successCallback(json) {
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log('There was an error editing the data', response);
    });
  }
```

Server side function

```
function update(req, res) {
  console.log('updating with data', req.body);
  db.Listing.findById(req.params.listingId, function(err, foundListing) {
    if(err) { console.log('listingsController.update error', err); }
    foundListing.topic = req.body.topic;
    foundListing.description = req.body.description;
    foundListing.budget = req.body.budget;
    foundListing.location = req.body.location;
    foundListing.save(function(err, savedListing) {
      if(err) { console.log('saving altered listing failed'); }
      res.json(savedListing);
    });
  });

}
```

After clicking this:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
     <h4 class='inline-header'>Topic:</h4>
     <span ng-hide="editing"> {{listingShowCtrl.listing.topic}}</a></span>
     <input ng-show="editing" ng- model="listingShowCtrl.listing.topic"type="text" class="form-control input-md">
 </li>
...
<div class='panel-footer'>
    <div class='panel-footer'>
    <button class='btn btn-info' ng-hide="editing" ng-click="editing = true">Edit Listing</button>
    <button class='btn btn-success' ng-show="editing" ngclick="listingShowCtrl.editListing(listing); editing = false">Save Changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? you get data from `$http` on click. You don't store it so I don't see any problem

Comment: The data seems to be wiped out after I save any change.  I am not sure, but I think the fields are not matching up somehow so it registers a blank object on save.

Comment: Have you checked your server API with other tools like postman ??

Comment: You haven't shown us how you load your data, only how you update it. There is no code for retrieving the listing. How do you expect it to magically appear on a page reload?

Comment: So I am realizing the problem is that my req.body is a blank object and so when I save, it overwrites everything.  I have body-parser and I can successfully create a new object. Is there something I am missing to show the correct req.body?